# How can I print a document out so that each page is printed twice as small on each page?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, openoffice

How can I (in Word or Open Office) print out a document so that each page is printed twice, two times as small, and rotated on each page, like this:

[image]

Comment: I think subman's answer is great, and would give the same advice, but if you're using a regular printer than isn't ancient, there's probably a printer setting for this too in the print dialogue if you look (but it would be different for different printers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using PDF creator

1. Download and install [PDF creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)
2. In Word or OpenOffice, go to Print options, choose 2 copies, untick 'Collate', set the printer to 'PDF creator'. Click Print.
   [image]
3. On the PDF creator screen choose Options.
   [image]
4. On the Options screen, choose Print and tick the 'Print after saving' checkbox. Save the options, and Save the PDF.
   [image]
5. You will be prompted to print the document, choose the 'PDF printer' again. 
   [image]
6. Save this second PDF. You will be prompted again to print the document, choose Cancel this time.
7. Open the second PDF file in a [PDF viewer](http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/). It should contain 2 copies of each page.
8. In the PDF viewer, go to Print options and change Page Scaling to 'Multiple pages per sheet'. Change pages per sheet to 2. Print the final document to a real printer.
   [image]

Remember to go back into the PDFcreator options and untick the 'Print after saving' checkbox when you are finished.